# Installing Phonegap on Windows 7 : The command 'android' failed

Tags: android, windows, cordova, installation

I followed the documentation and some tutorials on Phonegap to install it on Windows 7, but I'm stuck.

So far, I've installed Java 1.7.0_06, Ant-Apache 1.9.2, Eclipse, Android SDK with Android 4.3 (API 18), all Tools and all Extras in the SDK Manager), NodeJS 0.10.18 and Git.

I wrote all paths in the PATH variables in Windows it's look like this (decomposed) :

```
F:\nodejs;
F:\android-sdk\sdk\platform-tools;
F:\android-sdk\sdk\tools;
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
%ANT_HOME%\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

Where %JAVA_HOME% and %ANT_HOME% have the right path, they give me the their version when I type java -version or ant -version in the CLI

So I went in the CLI, I installed Phonegap with the following command :

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

It give me the 3.0.0-0.14.3 version when I type phonegap -v.

Now, I went to my folder F:\apps and I created a new project with the following command :

```
phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

Everything goes well, the files are created.

I went in the 'hello' folder, and I typed this command :

```
phonegap local build android
```

And there come the problem, I get this error :

```
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
[error] The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest AndroidSDK installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path. Output:
```

I tried this command too :

```
phonegap build android
```

But it get stuck at this, nothing happen next :

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the remote environment
[phonegap] compressing the app...
```

After lot's of research, I don't know what I can do anymore to find the problem, and I'm quiet new with all this CLI... So yeah, do you have any idea why the command 'android' failed ?

Thanks

Comment: did you solve this ? how ?

Comment: Hi, see my answer below, that's how I solved it : When I typed "android" in my CMD, it showed that 'xcopy' was not recognized. I searched on google, so I added these paths : %SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;

Answer (score 5):

Open environment variables, on the first part 'user variables' add new variable with this name android and the variable F:\android-sdk\sdk\tools;

Then edit the user variables PATH and add this at end of the line %android%;
close your CMD and try again.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your answer.

I already had these variables in my PATH, but I found the one that were missing !

When I typed "android" in my CMD, it showed that 'xcopy' was not recognized. I searched on google, so I added these paths :

    %SystemRoot%\system32;
    %SystemRoot%;
    %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;

And now everything works well :)