# cordova error ENOENT

Tags: android, npm, cordova-3

I'm trying to add android platform using cordova but i'm getting that error.

[image]

I have problem adding wp7, wp8 and windows 8 as shown below:

[image]

I tried a few things found here [Phonegap Build android - error "Adding the android platform" ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215457/phonegap-build-android-error-adding-the-android-platform-enoent) but doesnt help me. Anyone have any idea how to solve this??

Comment: let me know if you got problem after you try my solution

Answer (score 5):

If after type `android` in `cmd` says: `'xcopy' was not recognized.`

then add to your path: `%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;`

After 3 days trying to solve the same issue, finally I found the solution. Thank's to:
[Installing Phonegap on Windows 7 : The command 'android' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903494/installing-phonegap-on-windows-7-the-command-android-failed)
(I can't add comments yet)

Answer (score 1):

Download and install node.js

http://nodejs.org/

Install ant using brew and set `ANDROID_HOME` to your path.

Download and install Homebrew by executing following command in terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Install Apache Ant via Homebrew by executing

```
brew install ant
```

set `ANDROID_HOME` to your path

```
%ANDROID_HOME%;
```

Comment: i tried but i'm running on windows 7 and doesnt recognize ruby command so i can't install homebrew

Comment: install node.js first