# Getting ENOENT error on Cordova

Tags: cordova

Getting this error every time:

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT at ChileProcess.whenDone 
C:\> [user path]\AppData\Roamin\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-
lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23>...
```

http://i57.tinypic.com/2s6rgvk.png

Environment Variables all are set

Comment: Did you try this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395736/cordova-error-enoent?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: The error should be included in the post. This will prevent this question from becoming useless in the event the picture is no longer available.