# Getting Error when I add platform android in cordova phongegap project

Tags: android, cordova

> I am using cordova 5.4.0 on windows. Everything works fine but when i
>   add the platform through command `cordova platform add android`
>   getting error

```
Adding android project...
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\PRABHU\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-andr
oid\4.1.1\package\bin\create.bat C:\Users\PRABHU\hello\platforms\android com.exa
mple.hello HelloDemo --cli""
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

> I have install all the software **Node js, winAnt, Java jdk, Android
>   studio**
>   please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Check the internet connection.

Comment: @HRCJ there is no issue in internet connection

Comment: open in Node.js console and run that commands.

Comment: @HRCJ which command have to rund in node console??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395736/cordova-error-enoent

Comment: @Shubhank not resolve